# How to get merged cell (starting and ending addresses) of XSSF sheet apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

### related to java apache poi XSSF file reading

i am confused in getting starting and ending indexes of a XSSF excel sheet kindly help me out as early as possible.

Comment: Do you mean starting/ending of a specific merged cell or first/last cell-number of the whole sheet?

Answer (score 1):

`List<CellRangeAddress> mergedRegions = worksheet.getMergedRegions()`

on that mergedCells you no can find all MergedCells and call the appropriate method to get the start and end of row and column.

There also is a helper class but I currently do not know the name and do not have access so I could have lookup in the code I have used that.